# How to generate the type of an example without exporting the example?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following example object:

```
const exampleResponse = {
  "rates": [{
    "cost": 10,
    "description": "10$ shipping"
    }, {
    "cost": 20,
    "description": "20$ shipping",
    "guaranteedDaysToDelivery": 5
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I can get the type of that example like so:

```
type SuccessResponse = typeof exampleResponse;
```

The problem is, if I compile the .ts file, my example is unnecessarily included in the export.

I only need the example type at compile time, then it can be discarded.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you only need it at compile time, why don't you just define the type?

Comment: @Behrooz I could, but im just being lazy and thought I could use typeof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only need the example type at compile time, then it can be discarded. Is there a way around this?

No. I am assuming you are getting this content as JSON and there are tools like [JSON to DTS](https://alm-tools.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/json-to-dts.html) that can convert your JSON to TypeScript declarations.